# For what do you need the "initalValue"

Tags: javascript, function

I saw this function:

```
function reduce(arr, fn, initial) {
 return (function step(idx, value) { 
   if(idx > arr.length - 1) 
      return value;
    return step(idx + 1, fn(value, arr[idx], idx, arr))    
   })(0, initial)

 }

module.exports = reduce
```

What does the "(0,inital)" stand for.

Comment: http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(0, initial)` there triggers the `step` function for the first time, passing in `0` as `idx` and `initial` (`reduce`'s parameter) as `value`. `step` then continues to call itself until it's done with the work.

It's clearer if we factor out the named function expression, which isn't serving any purpose here:

```
function reduce(arr, fn, initial) {
    // Define the step function:
    function step(idx, value) {
        if (idx > arr.length - 1)
            return value;
        return step(idx + 1, fn(value, arr[idx], idx, arr))
    }
    // Call it to start the process, return the final result it returns:
    return step((0, initial)
}
```